# Flutter Custom Painter disappears on tap/scroll

Tags: flutter

I have a CustomPainter:

```
class _Painter extends CustomPainter {
  _Painter({
    @required this.animation,
    this.strokeWidth,
    @required this.valuePercentage,
    @required this.color,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;

  final double strokeWidth;
  final double valuePercentage;
  final Color color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {    
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black12
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth ?? 5.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    canvas.drawCircle(size.center(Offset.zero), size.width / 2.0, paint);
    paint.color = color;
    double progressRadians =
        (valuePercentage != 0 ? valuePercentage : 1.0) * 2 * pi;
    canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & size, pi * 1.5, progressRadians, false, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_Painter other) {
    return valuePercentage != other.valuePercentage;
  }
}
```

Used like so, in a StatelessWidget:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: radius * 2,
          width: radius * 2,
          child: Center(
            child: CustomPaint(
              size: Size((radius - 3) * 2, (radius - 3) * 2),
              painter: _Painter(
                animation: animationController,
                strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
                valuePercentage: _valuePercentage,
                color: color,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // ...
      ],
    );
  }
```

The result:

[image]

Now, this happens:

[image]

Flutter v1.0.0, stable channel.

Comment: what do you need `animation: animationController` for? you are not using it in your `_Painter` class in any way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more debugging, I realized that this was caused by Flutter itself. Switching over to the master channel from the stable v1 channel (ironically) fixed the issue.